# Excel Addin RibbonBar shows old Buttons

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, excel-addins

I have an Excel addin which has a ribbonbar.
The ribbonbar has some buttons and checkboxes, etc.
Recently, I removed a checkbox and added a button instead.
The ribbonbar shows correctly in the designer but isn't showing the button in Excel.
It seems that the ribbonbar is not being updated.

In Designer:

[image]

InExcel:

[image]

I guess Visual Studio places the DLLs, etc. in a temp folder while debugging but I am not sure where this might be.
My question is: Why is the button not showing? Are there temporary files which may lead to this error?

When debugging, I can see that the visible property is set to true and that it is correctly added to the group.

Some info:
I am using Excel 2007 with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start debug session from visual studio the addin is installed. It is possible that visual studio did not reinstall the addin correctly. Can you try to remove the addin from excel explicitly following this steps:

1. Start Excel as you normally do (not from visual studio), Go to File -> Options -> Add-ins
2. From the **Manage** drop down pick **COM Add-ins** then click **Go**
3. Find your add-in mark it and click **Remove**

Now if you start new debug session probably the toolbar will be updated.
If this resolve the issue, the cause is as you've said it - related to some cached dll.

Comment: So easy and yet so powerfull. Thanks